# ffmpeg: which functions are multithreading safe?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have read (somewhere, don't remember and find it anymore right now - maybe the question would be obsolete for me otherwise anyway) that some FFmpeg functions are not safe to call from multiple threads at the same time.

FFmpeg itself is not multithreading safe in the sense that you shouldn't call `av_read_frame` or `avcodec_decode_audio4` on the same context from different threads at the same time - but that is mostly obvious.

But for example, it seems like `avformat_find_stream_info` even on separate contexts is not safe to be called from different threads at the same time. So to make that safe, you would need a global mutex.

Is there a list of the functions which are not safe?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some discussions I found: [here](http://libav-users.943685.n4.nabble.com/Threads-safe-issue-with-ffmpeg-c-td945683.html) or [here](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/libav-user/2011-November/000892.html)

From what I have found so far, it seems like only `avcodec_open` and `avcodec_close` are not thread safe.

However, the correct solution seems to be to use `av_lockmgr_register` to register a mutex handler in FFmpeg which is then called automatically by FFmpeg at the needed places. See [here](http://ffmpeg.sourcearchive.com/documentation/0.6/avcodec_8h_e120ec60cdf49cf0f793eff3ec731bcc.html#e120ec60cdf49cf0f793eff3ec731bcc) or [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/libav-user@mplayerhq.hu/msg03730.html). Also Chrome does that, see [here](http://src.chromium.org/svn/branches/1229_12/src/media/filters/ffmpeg_glue.cc).

Comment: just want to mention that avformat_find_stream_info isn't thread safe too.

Comment: If you build FFmpeg with `--enable-pthreads`, FFmpeg automatically uses its own default lock manager implementation, so there's no need to call `av_lockmgr_register()`.

Comment: `av_lockmgr_register` is "now" deprecated and is a no-op. At least as of release 4.2.2, maybe earlier. The comment on that function reads "This function does nothing, and always returns 0. Be sure to build with thread support to get basic thread safety."